# Impossible Nas in wrld_simpl

Tags: r, raster

When I create a raster of the world land based on wrld_simpl (or any other environmental layer coming from worldclim) always appear to be some "impossible" NAs on land. Why would that happen? I need a perfect mask of the world land to excerpt records that did not fall in the ocean. However, there are many records on land and still are considered NA.

My script goes like this:

```
require(raster)
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
x=read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncvu64r2fxgfd4e/NAlocations.csv?dl=0")
r=raster(ncols=360,nrows=(180))
extent(r)=extent(wrld_simpl)
r=rasterize(wrld_simpl,r,wrld_simpl$AREA)
plot(r)
x=x[-which(is.na(extract(r,x$lon,x$lat))),]# This should eliminate all locations on land.
points(x$lon,x$lat, col="red", cex=.3)
```

How is that possible? And would it be a way to create a clean raster for the world land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct `read.csv` from dropbox does not work for me.
If I do

```
z <- extract(r, x)
# NOT z <- extract(r, x[,1], x[,2]) !!! 

i <- which(is.na(z))
points(x[i,])
```

I see a bunch of points in the water of the coast of Mozambique.